# User search data with ranking; what's the reputation for?

Tags: support, reputation, users-page, rankings

[image]

Below the name "0" is displayed, I can understand this is some reputation but on what basis is it granted?

Comment: See how `week` is underlined. You have earned 0 reputation this week.

Comment: See the word week is underlined on the top right of the screenshot. That's the amount of reputation they gained this week.

Comment: Oh that was easy, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reputation shown in the list is the amount of reputation you earned in the selected period on the right (so it's a ranking list comparable to the [reputation leagues](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/)). You can compare the difference between the options:

- [week](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=month&search=bijendra)

  [image]
- [month](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=month&search=bijendra)

  [image]
- [year](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=year&search=bijendra)

  [image]